# Typerror: object is not subscriptable Django test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, typeerror

I have some problems with my tests in Django.

The ide is that I create questions for my learning platform, and I want to verify that the questions are actually created. The problem is that (from what I understand) I try to put a list, objects that in a list cannot fit.

Do you have any ideas how I can correct this?

Thank you very much!

Error:

```
response.context['latest_question_list'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The test:

```
def test_two_types_questions(self):
        """
        The questions index page may display multiple questions.
        """
        lab1 = Lab.objects.create(lab_name="test lab past question", pub_date=datetime.now(), lab_theory="test lab past question")
        question1 = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab1, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer='1')
        question2 = QuestionFillText(lab=lab1, text1='1', text2='2', answer='1')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('labs:index'))
        print(response)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            [question1, question2],
        )
```

**Models.py**

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    lab_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, unique=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    lab_theory = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lab_name

class QuestionMultipleChoice(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = QuestionType.multiplechoice
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    answer = models.IntegerField(max_length=200,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    @property
    def html_name(self):
        return "q_mc_{}".format(self.pk)

    @property
    def correct_answer(self):
        correct_answer_number = int(self.answer)
        correct_answer = getattr(self, "option{}".format(correct_answer_number))
        return correct_answer

    def check_answer(self, given):
        return self.correct_answer == given
```

**UPDATE**

i changed the logic of the tests, to check "**str**" but i get nothing back (test is skipped):

```
    def test_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past are displayed on the
        index page.
        """
        past_date = date(1997, 3, 2)
        lab2 = Lab.objects.create(lab_name="test lab past question", pub_date=past_date, lab_theory="test lab past question")
        past_question = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab2, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer='1')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('labs:index'))
        print (response)
        self.assertEqual(str(past_question),'This is a test question')
```

Comment: From the error, the response `context` is empty, what details are you expecting in the response exactly?

Comment: It should be ``response.data[]`` instead of ``response.context[]``

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: "AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'data'"

Comment: @neilharia7 the idea is that I should see the list of the generated questions. I'll add the code part for the model.

Comment: Hello @mdem99 when you print response what you're getting ?

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari if i do print(response) i get nothing back, or at least i can't see anything from the test execution.