# Django Unit Test not executed

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models

I'm still struggling with tests in Django. Now i've rewrite a test, but it's not executed, so i see no results when i run the test command. Is it because of the wrong test or i'm missing something?
Thank you once again :)

Models:

```
class Lab(models.Model):
    lab_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, unique=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    lab_theory = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lab_name

class QuestionMultipleChoice(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = QuestionType.multiplechoice
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    answer = models.IntegerField(max_length=200,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    @property
    def html_name(self):
        return "q_mc_{}".format(self.pk)

    @property
    def correct_answer(self):
        correct_answer_number = int(self.answer)
        correct_answer = getattr(self, "option{}".format(correct_answer_number))
        return correct_answer

    def check_answer(self, given):
        return self.correct_answer == given
```

Test:

```
    def test_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past are displayed on the
        index page.
        """
        past_date = date(1997, 3, 2)
        lab2 = Lab.objects.create(lab_name="test lab past question", pub_date=past_date, lab_theory="test lab past question")
        past_question = QuestionMultipleChoice.objects.create(lab=lab2, question='This is a test question', option1='1', option2='2', option3='3', option4='4', answer='1')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('labs:index'))
        print (response)
        self.assertEqual(str(past_question),'This is a test question')
```

Comment: The test has a `self` argument but no class?

Answer (score 2):

For a test to be discovered by Django's `DiscoverRunner`, it should meet the following criteria:

- The method must start with `test_`
- The method should be in a class that inherits from `django.test.TestCase`
- The `TestCase` should be in a file that follows the `test*.py` glob pattern.
- If you have `myapp.tests` as a module, all files under it must still meet the `test*.py` glob match *and* there must be an `__init__.py` from that `tests` module.

These should hold true unless you switch out the `TEST_RUNNER` for Pytest or something else. I may be missing something so let me know if these are true and I can edit the comment with more details regarding your specific situation.

Some [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/#using-different-testing-frameworks) and the [`DiscoverRunner` source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/91acfc3514280370535f1dd6bebee57760bac7b9/django/test/runner.py#L555).

Comment: Hi Dan, yes i already have all the points. I just put the "code part" of the test that is not executed. The other tests are actually executed. This is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70470534/12342019) that i've made